# Blocking UI thread dosen't render UI components of an other window

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my application I have a scenario where I need to block the UI Thread when I perform an action. While its blocked I have an other window that needs to show a message saying "performing action please wait" when the UI is blocked. Problem is the window shows up but it never displays the message. Please help. Even DoEvents() dosen't help. It just so lightly displays the message

Note:

1. I don't want the method as async because I want to block the UI when it runs.
2. I don't want to say ShowDialog() because it just blocks there.

```
 private void ViewModel_PerformPrimeAction(InstrumentAction Action)
    {
                bool abort = false;

                CommandRunningWindow cmdDialog = null;
                if (Action == InstrumentAction.Prime)
                {
                    if (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show((string)TryFindResource("ConfirmPrimeInstrument"),
                        ApplicationSettingsViewModel.Instance.ProductName, MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                        return;

                    this.IsEnabled = false;
//This below line never shows the message.
                    cmdDialog = ShowCommandWindow(ViewModelsHelper.GetResourceString("PerformingPrime")); 

                   System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); 
                }
                UIUtils.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;

                try
                {
                    // This operation takes 10 seconds
                    QXInstrumentViewModel.Instance.Prime(() => { if (abort) throw new RunAbortedException(null); });

                }
                catch (RunAbortedException)
                {
                    errorMessage = (string)TryFindResource("CompletePrimeInstrumentAborted");
                    cmdDialog?.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var message = QXInstrumentViewModel.ToErrorCode(ex);
                    TokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationToken(true);
                    if (message != null)
                    {
                        errorMessage = string.Format((string)TryFindResource("CompletePrimeInstrumentWithError"), Convert.ToInt32(message), errorMessage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorMessage = (string)TryFindResource("CompletePrimeInstrumentWithUnknownError");
                    }
                    cmdDialog?.Close();
                }
                UIUtils.OverrideCursor = null;
                this.IsEnabled = true; 
    }

     public CommandRunningWindow ShowCommandWindow(string message)
            {
                CommandRunningWindow cmdDialog = new CommandRunningWindow();
                cmdDialog.Message = message;
                cmdDialog.Owner = WPFUtils.GetActiveWindow();
                cmdDialog.Show();
                return cmdDialog;
            }
```

The CommandRunningWindow has a dependency property of type string (message) that is bound to a textblock.

Comment: Don't block the UI thread.  It's just going to cause you problems.  If you want to prevent the user from interacting with a portion of the UI then *disable those portions of the UI*, don't block the UI thread.

Comment: I want to block the UI, but I don't want to block the UI. Sounds like you want to go swimming without becoming wet. Take a step back and think about it again.

Comment: Hmm ok I want to disable the controls but probem is, it never stays on the current window. As soon as the operation is complete, it just swirtches to an other tab even without user action. It was implemented that way from an other place. So I thought if there was an easy way out.

Comment: So i did something like this not sure if its an ideal way if anyone can correct me. I made the method async. I added await Task.Delay(100); after the show dalog step,

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't just pop up a modal dialog box?

Answer (score -1):

You can't both block and show a message on the same thread simultaneously.

What you should do is to execute your long-running operation on a background thread - the easiest way to do this is to start a [TPL task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) - and display the message on the UI thread. You may still disable the window. Just make sure that you don't touch the UI on the background thread where your long-running operation executes.

```
private void ViewModel_PerformPrimeAction(InstrumentAction Action)
{
    bool abort = false;

    CommandRunningWindow cmdDialog = null;
    if (Action == InstrumentAction.Prime)
    {
        if (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show((string)TryFindResource("ConfirmPrimeInstrument"),
            ApplicationSettingsViewModel.Instance.ProductName, MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            return;

        this.IsEnabled = false;
        //This below line never shows the message.
        cmdDialog = ShowCommandWindow(ViewModelsHelper.GetResourceString("PerformingPrime"));
    }
    UIUtils.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // This operation takes 10 seconds
        QXInstrumentViewModel.Instance.Prime(() => { if (abort) throw new RunAbortedException(null); });
    })
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            if (task.Exception != null && task.Exception.GetBaseException() is RunAbortedException)
            {
                var message = QXInstrumentViewModel.ToErrorCode(ex);
                TokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationToken(true);
                if (message != null)
                {
                    errorMessage = string.Format((string)TryFindResource("CompletePrimeInstrumentWithError"), Convert.ToInt32(message), errorMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    errorMessage = (string)TryFindResource("CompletePrimeInstrumentWithUnknownError");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = (string)TryFindResource("CompletePrimeInstrumentAborted");
            }
        }
        cmdDialog?.Close();
        UIUtils.OverrideCursor = null;
        this.IsEnabled = true;
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```